# Asynchronously execute two applescript in cocoa application

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsapplescript

I am converting all iwork documents file OSX type to Microsoft file type like .pages to .doc .keynotes to .pdf and .numbers to .xls. I have written 3 different script for each type and calling an event with arguments from cocoa application (NSAppleScript, NSAppleEventDescriptor). If I call that all the scripts serially, its working fine. But, when I go for concurrent operation also its conversion is happening one by one only.

I want to open all three documents open and conversion should happen concurrently.how to implement the logic for this problem.

How to do asynchronous action in applescript.

Can anyone suggest a solution that would give me the same behaviour as the NSAppleScript, NSAppleScriptEventDescriptor method gives me?